# Font creation using NGUI in unity3d

Tags: fonts, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, multi-touch, ngui

I am new to NGUI concept in unity 3d.

i tried to create a new font using NGUI, But failed.

Can you explain how can i  create a new font using NGUI.

I have to make goonspectreTBS font.

Waiting for positive response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 2 YouTube videos [NGUI Update 1.6 at minute 3](http://youtu.be/4JW4M7wbzeo) and [NGUI: Packed Fonts](http://youtu.be/dY6jQ7d2ius) from the maker of NGUI

Comment: NGUI has abilities only for using raster fonts created by other applications like http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/, http://www.71squared.com/glyphdesigner/.

Comment: i have to make goonspectreTBS font using ngui. any solution for it??

Comment: @Kay gave you a tip. SO is not here to write your code for you, the answers to font creation are eminently searchable on the NGUI website.

Comment: i created font as in videos. But font is crashed. So word in label cant read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways of introducing custom fonts to NGUI.
You should definitely go through NGUI tutorials, they explaining all processes step by step

You can find it here 
http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=197